# What is Vec<(i64, i64)> data type in Rust?

Tags: vector, types, rust, syntax

I have the function

```
fn convert_fracts(l: Vec<(i64, i64)>) -> Vec<(i64, i64)>
```

but I don't understand what the type definitely is. I have just thought it is vector of pairs but later I have understood it must be not. Is it a vector of slices or another?

Comment: It is a vector of tuples that contain two `i64`'s - a vector of pairs.

Comment: "I have just thought it is vector of pairs but later I have understood it must be not." – What makes you think it is *not* a vector of pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rust, a tuple `(A, B)` is a pair of values. It's different from an array of length 2, e.g. `[A; 2]`, because the types of the two values can be different. A tuple can have more than two elements, and is a convenient way to pass around multiple values at once, without having to define a new struct for one-off use cases.

In your case, you have a vector of tuples, which are pairs of `i64`.